# How can I read flat repeating xml attributes into separate objects

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xml-parsing

I have an XML file that contains some results that I need to read into separate objects. My problem is that the data is contained in a single node.

The attributes that I need to read also change for different results, so it is not as simple as using something like TAKE.

This is a single result:

```
<AnalyteCode>HEM</AnalyteCode>
<AnalyteName>HEM</AnalyteName>
<Result>18.0</Result>
<ResultText>0</ResultText>
```

but, and so is this:

```
<AnalyteCode>ALP</AnalyteCode>
<AnalyteName>ALP SerPl-cCnc</AnalyteName>
<Result>52.0</Result>
<Units>U/L</Units>
<LowRange>20.0</LowRange>
<HighRange>150.0</HighRange>
```

I have omitted some XML for brevity

```
<LabResults>
    <LabResult>
        <LabResultHeader>
            <TestCode>CDP</TestCode>
            <TestName>Comprehensive Diagnostic</TestName>
            <TestType>R</TestType>
            <ResultDate>2019-06-14T12:08:41-07:00</ResultDate>
            <ResultStatus>Done</ResultStatus>
            <DeviceID>XXXXXXYYYYYZZZZZ</DeviceID>
        </LabResultHeader>
        <LabResultItems>
            <LabResultItem>
                <AnalyteCode>HEM</AnalyteCode>
                <AnalyteName>HEM</AnalyteName>
                <Result>18.0</Result>
                <ResultText>0</ResultText>
                <AnalyteCode>LIP</AnalyteCode>
                <AnalyteName>LIP</AnalyteName>
                <Result>107.0</Result>
                <ResultText>0</ResultText>
                <AnalyteCode>ICT</AnalyteCode>
                <AnalyteName>ICT</AnalyteName>
                <Result>0.0</Result>
                <ResultText>0</ResultText>
                <AnalyteCode>ALB</AnalyteCode>
                <AnalyteName>Alb SerPl-mCnc</AnalyteName>
                <Result>37.0</Result>
                <Units>g/L</Units>
                <LowRange>25.0</LowRange>
                <HighRange>44.0</HighRange>
                <AnalyteCode>ALP</AnalyteCode>
                <AnalyteName>ALP SerPl-cCnc</AnalyteName>
                <Result>52.0</Result>
                <Units>U/L</Units>
                <LowRange>20.0</LowRange>
                <HighRange>150.0</HighRange>
                <AnalyteCode>ALT</AnalyteCode>
                <AnalyteName>ALT SerPl-cCnc</AnalyteName>
                <Result>54.0</Result>
                <Units>U/L</Units>
                <LowRange>10.0</LowRange>
                <HighRange>118.0</HighRange>
                <AnalyteCode>AMY</AnalyteCode>
                <AnalyteName>Amylase SerPl-cCnc</AnalyteName>
                <Result>320.0</Result>
                <Units>U/L</Units>
                <LowRange>200.0</LowRange>
                <HighRange>1200.0</HighRange>
                <AnalyteCode>TBIL</AnalyteCode>
                <AnalyteName>Bilirub SerPl-sCnc</AnalyteName>
                <Result>4.0</Result>
                <Units>umol/L</Units>
                <LowRange>2.0</LowRange>
                <HighRange>10.0</HighRange>
                <AnalyteCode>BUN</AnalyteCode>
                <AnalyteName>BUN SerPl-sCnc</AnalyteName>
                <Result>4.8</Result>
                <Units>mmol/L</Units>
                <LowRange>2.5</LowRange>
                <HighRange>8.9</HighRange>
                <AnalyteCode>CA</AnalyteCode>
                <AnalyteName>Calcium SerPl-sCnc</AnalyteName>
                <Result>2.87</Result>
                <Units>mmol/L</Units>
                <LowRange>2.15</LowRange>
                <HighRange>2.95</HighRange>
                <AnalyteCode>PHOS</AnalyteCode>
                <AnalyteName>Phosphate SerPl-sCnc</AnalyteName>
                <ResultText>2.38 *</ResultText>
                <Units>mmol/L</Units>
                <LowRange>0.94</LowRange>
                <HighRange>2.13</HighRange>
                <Notes>H</Notes>
                <AnalyteCode>CRE</AnalyteCode>
                <AnalyteName>Creat SerPl-sCnc</AnalyteName>
                <Result>57.0</Result>
                <Units>umol/L</Units>
                <LowRange>27.0</LowRange>
                <HighRange>124.0</HighRange>
                <AnalyteCode>GLU</AnalyteCode>
                <AnalyteName>Glucose SerPl-sCnc</AnalyteName>
                <ResultText>6.2 *</ResultText>
                <Units>mmol/L</Units>
                <LowRange>3.3</LowRange>
                <HighRange>6.1</HighRange>
                <Notes>H</Notes>
                <AnalyteCode>NA+</AnalyteCode>
                <AnalyteName>Sodium SerPl-sCnc</AnalyteName>
                <Result>149.0</Result>
                <Units>mmol/L</Units>
                <LowRange>138.0</LowRange>
                <HighRange>160.0</HighRange>
                <AnalyteCode>K+</AnalyteCode>
                <AnalyteName>Potassium SerPl-sCnc</AnalyteName>
                <Result>4.7</Result>
                <Units>mmol/L</Units>
                <LowRange>3.7</LowRange>
                <HighRange>5.8</HighRange>
                <AnalyteCode>TP</AnalyteCode>
                <AnalyteName>Prot SerPl-mCnc</AnalyteName>
                <Result>58.0</Result>
                <Units>g/L</Units>
                <LowRange>54.0</LowRange>
                <HighRange>82.0</HighRange>
                <AnalyteCode>GLOB</AnalyteCode>
                <AnalyteName>Globulin SerPl Calc-mCnc</AnalyteName>
                <ResultText>21 *</ResultText>
                <Units>g/L</Units>
                <LowRange>23.0</LowRange>
                <HighRange>52.0</HighRange>
                <Notes>L</Notes>
            </LabResultItem>
        </LabResultItems>
    </LabResult>
</LabResults>
```

Comment: Can you change your XML to put each result in a separate `LabResultItem` tag?

Comment: Please note that XML in the post has *no attributes* at all. Xml node/element and attributes are very different, in particular you can't have "repeating XML attributes" and there is no order between attributes ...

Comment: @DourHighArch, unfortunately the xml is from a third party and they won't change,  nor do they realize the importance of correctly formatted xml.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If each result is always expected to start with one attribute (eg; "AnalyteCode"), then you can parse each group using this as the "starting" delimiter.

I created some sample code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml;

namespace Test_20191203
{
    public class LabResultItem
    {
        public string AnalyteCode { get; set; }
        public string AnalyteName { get; set; }
        public string Result { get; set; }
        public string ResultText { get; set; }
        public string Units { get; set; }
        public string LowRange { get; set; }
        public string HighRange { get; set; }
        public string Notes { get; set; }
    }

    public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string startProperty = nameof(LabResultItem.AnalyteCode);

            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.LoadXml(input);

            List<LabResultItem> results = new List<LabResultItem>();
            LabResultItem currentItem = new LabResultItem();
            foreach (XmlNode node in doc.SelectSingleNode("/LabResults/LabResult/LabResultItems/LabResultItem").ChildNodes)
            {
                if (node.Name == startProperty)
                {
                    results.Add(currentItem);
                    currentItem = new LabResultItem();
                }

                var prop = typeof(LabResultItem).GetProperty(node.Name);
                if(prop == null)
                {
                    throw new Exception($"Invalid node found in xml: '{node.Name}', property must be a part of {nameof(LabResultItem)}");
                }
                prop.SetValue(currentItem, node.InnerText, null);
            }

            foreach(var result in results)
            {
                // iterate through results
            }
        }

        const string input = @"<LabResults>
    <LabResult>
        <LabResultHeader>
            <TestCode>CDP</TestCode>
            <TestName>Comprehensive Diagnostic</TestName>
            <TestType>R</TestType>
            <ResultDate>2019-06-14T12:08:41-07:00</ResultDate>
            <ResultStatus>Done</ResultStatus>
            <DeviceID>XXXXXXYYYYYZZZZZ</DeviceID>
        </LabResultHeader>
        <LabResultItems>
            <LabResultItem>
                <AnalyteCode>HEM</AnalyteCode>
                <AnalyteName>HEM</AnalyteName>
                <Result>18.0</Result>
                <ResultText>0</ResultText>
                <AnalyteCode>LIP</AnalyteCode>
                <AnalyteName>LIP</AnalyteName>
                <Result>107.0</Result>
                <ResultText>0</ResultText>
                <AnalyteCode>ICT</AnalyteCode>
                <AnalyteName>ICT</AnalyteName>
                <Result>0.0</Result>
                <ResultText>0</ResultText>
                <AnalyteCode>ALB</AnalyteCode>
                <AnalyteName>Alb SerPl-mCnc</AnalyteName>
                <Result>37.0</Result>
                <Units>g/L</Units>
                <LowRange>25.0</LowRange>
                <HighRange>44.0</HighRange>
                <AnalyteCode>ALP</AnalyteCode>
                <AnalyteName>ALP SerPl-cCnc</AnalyteName>
                <Result>52.0</Result>
                <Units>U/L</Units>
                <LowRange>20.0</LowRange>
                <HighRange>150.0</HighRange>
                <AnalyteCode>ALT</AnalyteCode>
                <AnalyteName>ALT SerPl-cCnc</AnalyteName>
                <Result>54.0</Result>
                <Units>U/L</Units>
                <LowRange>10.0</LowRange>
                <HighRange>118.0</HighRange>
                <AnalyteCode>AMY</AnalyteCode>
                <AnalyteName>Amylase SerPl-cCnc</AnalyteName>
                <Result>320.0</Result>
                <Units>U/L</Units>
                <LowRange>200.0</LowRange>
                <HighRange>1200.0</HighRange>
                <AnalyteCode>TBIL</AnalyteCode>
                <AnalyteName>Bilirub SerPl-sCnc</AnalyteName>
                <Result>4.0</Result>
                <Units>umol/L</Units>
                <LowRange>2.0</LowRange>
                <HighRange>10.0</HighRange>
                <AnalyteCode>BUN</AnalyteCode>
                <AnalyteName>BUN SerPl-sCnc</AnalyteName>
                <Result>4.8</Result>
                <Units>mmol/L</Units>
                <LowRange>2.5</LowRange>
                <HighRange>8.9</HighRange>
                <AnalyteCode>CA</AnalyteCode>
                <AnalyteName>Calcium SerPl-sCnc</AnalyteName>
                <Result>2.87</Result>
                <Units>mmol/L</Units>
                <LowRange>2.15</LowRange>
                <HighRange>2.95</HighRange>
                <AnalyteCode>PHOS</AnalyteCode>
                <AnalyteName>Phosphate SerPl-sCnc</AnalyteName>
                <ResultText>2.38 *</ResultText>
                <Units>mmol/L</Units>
                <LowRange>0.94</LowRange>
                <HighRange>2.13</HighRange>
                <Notes>H</Notes>
                <AnalyteCode>CRE</AnalyteCode>
                <AnalyteName>Creat SerPl-sCnc</AnalyteName>
                <Result>57.0</Result>
                <Units>umol/L</Units>
                <LowRange>27.0</LowRange>
                <HighRange>124.0</HighRange>
                <AnalyteCode>GLU</AnalyteCode>
                <AnalyteName>Glucose SerPl-sCnc</AnalyteName>
                <ResultText>6.2 *</ResultText>
                <Units>mmol/L</Units>
                <LowRange>3.3</LowRange>
                <HighRange>6.1</HighRange>
                <Notes>H</Notes>
                <AnalyteCode>NA+</AnalyteCode>
                <AnalyteName>Sodium SerPl-sCnc</AnalyteName>
                <Result>149.0</Result>
                <Units>mmol/L</Units>
                <LowRange>138.0</LowRange>
                <HighRange>160.0</HighRange>
                <AnalyteCode>K+</AnalyteCode>
                <AnalyteName>Potassium SerPl-sCnc</AnalyteName>
                <Result>4.7</Result>
                <Units>mmol/L</Units>
                <LowRange>3.7</LowRange>
                <HighRange>5.8</HighRange>
                <AnalyteCode>TP</AnalyteCode>
                <AnalyteName>Prot SerPl-mCnc</AnalyteName>
                <Result>58.0</Result>
                <Units>g/L</Units>
                <LowRange>54.0</LowRange>
                <HighRange>82.0</HighRange>
                <AnalyteCode>GLOB</AnalyteCode>
                <AnalyteName>Globulin SerPl Calc-mCnc</AnalyteName>
                <ResultText>21 *</ResultText>
                <Units>g/L</Units>
                <LowRange>23.0</LowRange>
                <HighRange>52.0</HighRange>
                <Notes>L</Notes>
            </LabResultItem>
        </LabResultItems>
    </LabResult>
</LabResults>";
    }
}
```

Comment: This is perfect and has put me on the right track.  Many thanks.  I should have asked hours ago.